# awk command stacks in top

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
total_pool=1
2
3
4
.
.
.
```

above is my variable name "total_pool" it has values of thousands in a single column.and It continuously change before every time I fire this script.
I want to parse each single entity of it in a loop..
The problem is this scripts runs from a crontab every 5 minutes..
and in my output of `top` command some times this query stacks !
like `/bin/awk -vRS= -vFS="\n" "{print $1}`  for a long long time..
How to stop this behavior ? any better approch ?
NOTE:I cannot use array as I have too old bash version.Which do not have array support.
So any better approch to grep data from a column variable one by one ??

```
#!/bin/sh
row=1
for POOL in ${total_pool} ;
do
        poolid=$(/bin/echo "$total_pool" | /bin/awk -vRS= -vFS="\n" "{print \$$row}"
        /usr/local/rrd/bin/rrdtool update /var/graphs/p${poolid}.rrd `NOW`:$upload
        row=`expr $row + 1`
done
```

Comment: And if I kil this  /bin/awk -vRS= -vFS="\n" "{print $1}  by "kill -9" It shows $2...$3.....in a continues manner

Comment: What's your desired final value for `poolid` in your example?

Comment: poolid is a one by one value of "total_pool" variable... which I will use in another process

Comment: What are you really trying to do? It appears from your script that you are repeatedly using some twisted `awk` logic to extract the first line of `${total_pool}`, which seems a bit pointless... Why not just capture it once and be done with it?

Comment: You really want to use /bin/bash, otherwise you're either using the bourne shell or an emulation of it. Bash has been able to handle arrays for more than a decade now.

Comment: actually i made some mistake..its not just a first line but the thousands of line stored in this variable.. see the changed question..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [echo's standard output is being buffered](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/). If [stdbuf from coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) is an option, you may want to use it to disable `echo`'s output buffering.

Comment: @user95711, assuming you have `stdbuf` installed, you could do something like `$(stdbuf -oL /bin/echo "$total_pool" | /bin/awk -vRS= -vFS="\n" "{print \$$row}")` within your loop